# gulp tap entering infinite loop

Tags: node.js, templates, pug, gulp

I'm trying to get the current file name inside the glob stream so that I can pass it to jade to properly name my templates.  Normally it would look like:

```
gulp.task('templatesjs', function() {
  gulp.src('src/templates/*.jade')
    .pipe(jade({
      client: true,
      name:"filenamehere"
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/templates'))
});
```

The only answer I found online to extract the filename in stream is by using gulp-tap:

```
gulp.task('templatesjs', function() {
  gulp.src('src/templates/*.jade')
    .pipe(tap(function(file, t) {
      var filename = file.relative.split('.')[0];
      return t.through(jade, [{client:true, name:filename}]);
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/templates'))
});
```

But for some reason this enters into an infinite loop.  If the glob matches index.jade for instance, the first iteration's file.relative is set to index.jade as espected, but then it gets caught in an infinite loop where file.relative is set to index.js, and the jade compiler crashes trying to compile the index.js file.  The reason I know this is because if I leave out the client:true option, file.relative is index.jade on the first iteration and index.html on all iterations after.  This of course doesn't crash but gets stuck in an infinite loop compiling index.html to index.html.

My solution is to check the file extension and only pipe through jade if I'm in an iteration containing a jade file.  This solves the infinite loop but it's sloppy and it copies a jade file into my build directory (not a huge deal).  It also only works on the first file, and all files after get the name of the first file.  I know I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out what.

```
gulp.task('templatesjs', function() {
  gulp.src('src/templates/*.jade')
    .pipe(tap(function(file, t) {
      sourcefile = file.relative;
      filename = sourcefile.split('.')[0]
      if(sourcefile.split('.')[sourcefile.split('.').length-1]!='js')
        return t.through(jade, [{client:true, name:filename}]);
      else
        return t;
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/templates'))
});
```

Comment: I eliminated the issue with copying the jade file to the build directory by  changing "return t;" to "return;" in the else block.

Answer (score 1):

With `through` you're duplicating the stream, effectively creating a stream of streams, hence the infinite loop.

This should work:

```
gulp.task('templatesjs', function() {
  gulp.src('src/templates/*.jade')
    .pipe(tap(function(file, t) {
      var filename = file.relative.split('.')[0];
      return gulp.src(file.path)
               .pipe(jade({client:true, name:filename}))
               .pipe(gulp.dest('build/templates'));
    })) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So I still don't really understand vinyl streams or tap but at least I got everything working using this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jade-jst-concat

and got it working in 3 minutes after struggling for 4 hours...

I could not get the other module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-tree-concat) to work even after modifying the example.  Hope this helps somebody with their client side gulp-jade modules.